# ErrorException Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: php, laravel

So i was trying to get a full post from the database by id, so when i click this link `<a href="{{ route('post.read', ['blog_id' => $blog->id]) }}" class="read-more">Lanjutkan Baca  <img src="asset/img/icons/double-arrow.png" alt="#"/></a>` it will take me to the `url /post/read/{id}` and give me the fullpost, but it shows that error,

i search for the same problem and found that that the problem is $blogs variable is an array, but the value it return is not, can anybody show me how to make the method or the view in my code to return an array and show the full post ?

this is my view read.blade.php

```
@foreach ($blogs as $blog)
                <div class="top-meta">{{ Carbon\Carbon::parse($blog->created_at)->format('d-m-Y')  }} /  di <a href="">Rakitan</a></div>
                    <h3>{{ $blog->name }}</h3>
                    <p>{!! $blog->message !!}</p>
@endforeach
```

this is my BlogController.php

```
public function getFullPost($blog_id) {
        $blogs = Blog::all()->where('blogs.id', '=', $blog_id)->first();
        return view('post.read')->with(compact('blogs'));
    }
```

this is the model Blog.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Blog extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['name','message'];
}
```

and this is the routes

```
Route::get('/post/read/{blog_id}', 'BlogController@getFullPost')->name('post.read');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use 'get' method to get all rows with cobditions

```
  public function getFullPost($blog_id) {
    $blogs = Blog::where('id', '=', $blog_id)->get();
    return view('post.read')->with(compact('blogs'));
  }
```

Add table name in Model to reference in Blog model

Comment: omg so that's how it works, thanks @Niklesh Raut it really helps